# mysql query with like operator and concate

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a table in which there a field name as path(text fiels) the entry of table is like following

Table name : Employee

```
EmpID                  path

1                      442

2                      443-442
```

I have used the following query

```
SELECT EmpID FROM Employee WHERE concat('-',path,'-') like '%442%'
```

The above query returns the  EmpID 1 and 2 but still i do not have clear understanding how the above query internally works, i was just using hit and trial method and fortunately i got the correct result .. now can anyone explain how the above query works internally

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

your query is taking the path, i.e. `422`, adding hyphens on the ends to turn it into `-422-` and then checking if the string `422` exists anywhere in it (which it does).

The % is a wildcard for any number of any characters. 
Is `-422-` like the string `(anything)422(anything)`? yes it is.

This will give the exact same results without the hyphen concatenation.

Comment: Ok Means It will only return the record containg 422 but if i will not add hyphen in

Comment: `Like '%422%'` returns all records containing 422 regardless of the hyphens or any other character or lack thereof.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [LIKE here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)